# I can't find tab control in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I using VS2010 professional edition. I can't find the **TabControl** anywhere. It's not only the tabControl, there are some others.

Do I need to download them from somewhere?

Thanks for helping

Comment: JQuery has tab widget, and someone told me that VS2010 has a similar control. I can't find it in the toolbox. However, I found documentation on TabControl on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx

Comment: windows app? web app? mvc app ? wpf app ? sl app? wtf app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you refer to is Windows Forms and the TabControl is in the ToolBox:

[image]

You mention jQuery and for ASP.Net applications to you need use controls like these:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
http://jquerytab.codeplex.com/
http://codecanyon.net/item/sliding-tabs-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/141774
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13165/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Tab-Control-Using-the-MultiView-c
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17292/Tab-control-for-ASP-NET-Applications